# Running a process in background in Perl

Tags: apache, perl

Update: Edited to make question more understandable.

I am creating a script which automatically parses an HTTP upload file and stores the information of the uploaded file like name, time of upload to another data file. These information are found in mod_security log file. mod_security has a rule in which we can redirect the uploaded file to a Perl script. In my case the Perl script is upload.pl. In this perl script I will scan the uploaded file using ClamAV antivirus. But the mod_sec only logs the uploaded file information like name, time of upload after the Perl script upload.pl is executed. But I am initiating another perl script execute.pl from upload.pl with a sleep(10) in execute.pl. The intention is that the execute.pl starts its function only after the completion of upload.pl. I need execute.pl to be executed as background process and upload.pl should complete without waiting the output of execute.pl.

But my issue is even I have made the execute.pl to run in background the HTTP upload waits for the completion of execute.pl even I have made the process to execute in background. I need the upload.pl to get complete without waiting the output of execute.pl. The script runs fine in console. For example I execute perl upload.pl from console the upload.pl completely executed without waiting the output of execute.pl. But when I try the same through apache, that means when I upload a sample file, the upload stucks for both the upload.pl and execute.pl to complete. Since execute.pl has been called from upload.pl as background process , the upload process should complete without waiting the output of execute.pl.

The methods I have tried so far are

```
 system("cmd &")
```

```
my $pid = fork();
if (defined($pid) && $pid==0) {
    # background process
    my $exit_code = system( $command );
    exit $exit_code >> 8;
}
```

```
my $pid = fork();
if (defined($pid) && $pid==0) {
    exec( $command );
}
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand! You tell us the name of some file but never refer to it again and you refer to a "first file" and a "second file" but never say which is which. You refer to a script which "does certain things" and tell us you get "console access" but not what you want it for nor why you need your "logger to log your logs" first.

Comment: @mark I have made changes

Comment: No clue what you are asking either. You say your issue is that you made some process wait for your two scripts to finish executing. If that's truly your issue, then it would seem the answer is "then take out the code you put it to do that!" But I suspect that's not your issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Rephrase of the question:**
How do I start a perl deamon process with a perl webscript?

**Answer:**
The key is to close the streams of the background job, since they are shared:

Webscript:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#print html header
print <<HTML;
Content-Type: text/html

<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title>Webscript</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=http://<your host>/webscript.pl" />
</head><body><pre>
HTML

#get the ps headers
print `ps -ef | grep STIME | grep -v grep`;

#get the running backgroundjobs
print `ps -ef | grep background.pl | grep -v grep`;

#find any running process...
$output = `cat /tmp/background.txt`;

#start the background job if there is no output yet
`<path of the background job>/background.pl &` unless $output;

#print the output file
print "\n\n---\n\n$output</pre></body></html>";
```

Background job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#close the shared streams!
close STDIN;
close STDOUT;
close STDERR;

#do something usefull!
for ( $i = 0; $i < 20; $i++ ) {
    open FILE, '>>/tmp/background.txt';
    printf FILE "Still running! (%2d seconds)\n", $i;
    close FILE;

    #getting tired of all the hard work...
    sleep 1;
}

#done
open FILE, '>>/tmp/background.txt';
printf FILE "Done! (%2d seconds)\n", $i;
close FILE;
```

Comment: Completly changed the solution, this time tested. Let me know if it works for you.